# Task scheduling algorithm with individual deadline

Tags: java, scheduling

I have n tasks, each has a specific deadline and time it takes to complete. However, I cannot complete all tasks with in their deadlines. I need to arrange these tasks in such a way to minimize the task's deadline over shoot time. Consider this case(left values are dead lines and right side values are time the task takes): 
 
2 2 
1 1 
4 3 
These three tasks can be done optimally like this:

time 1 : task 2 - task1 complete; 0 overshoot for task2 
time 2 : task 1
time 3 : task 1 - task2 complete; 1 overshoot for task1
time 4 : task 3
time 5 : task 3
time 6 : task 3 - task3 complete; 3 overshoot for task3

I need a faster algorithm for this; my goal is to find maximum overshoot of all overshoots(in above case its 3). Right now, i am sorting the tasks based on deadlines but its not fast, as when a new task is added, I should sort the whole list. Is there any other way?

---

After Lawrey's suggestion, I am using PriorityQueue but it is not giving me exact sorting.
This is my code:

```
class Compare2DArray implements Comparator<int[]> {
public int compare(int a[], int b[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++)
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return a[i] - b[i];
    return a.length - b.length;
}
}

public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfInputs= scan.nextInt();
        PriorityQueue<int[]> inputsList = new PriorityQueue<int[]>(numberOfInputs,new Compare2DArray());
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInputs; i++) {
            int[] input = new int[2];
            input[0] = scan.nextInt();
            input[1] = scan.nextInt();
            inputsList.add(input);

        }
    }
```

But this is sorting this queue of arrays

2 2 
1 1 
4 3 
10 1 
2 1 
 as 
1 1 
2 1 
4 3 
10 1 
2 2 
instead of
1 1 
2 1 
2 2 
4 3 
10 1 

The same comparator works fine over List sorting. I am not getting whats wrong with PriorityQueue

Comment: Here's the exactly same problem with appropriate solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430160/dyanmic-task-scheduling-interview-street/15342714

Answer (score 4):

**Priority Queue is implemented using heaps**. Hence, when you scan over the elements of priority queue it will not guarantee that it will give you all elements in sorted order. That is why you are not getting the desired sorted array.

I also faced the same problem for the question. I ended up using multimap in c++. But still the time complexity didn't improved much.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a really long list of tasks, e.g. millions, it shouldn't be taking that long.

However, what you need is likely to be a PriorityQueue which has O(1) add and O(ln N) take

Comment: I may have upto 100000 tasks. for each task added i need to calculate the optimum overshoot. So in 100000 case, i should sort 100000 times!

Comment: Then it can make a difference, try PriorityQueue which will be *much* faster.

Comment: I was hoping to find a better algorithm..is my approach right one(sorting based on deadlines then calculate overshoot)?

Comment: I suspect so. The PriorityQueue will give you the next entry in O(ln N) time.

Comment: How do i create a copy of PriorityQueue? I dont have get method for PriorityQueue, like in Lists.

Comment: PriorityQueue was added to Java 5.0 in 2004, you should have it as a built in.

Comment: Please refer to my question, its edited. I have a different queery now.

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting the same question (Its from interviewstreet, I suppose). Did you get this order:

1 1, 2 1, 4 3, 10 1, 2 2

when you printed the heap? Did you try popping items off the heap one by one and check their order? 
I am saying this since my implementation is in python and when I print the heap, I get the same order as you were saying. But that is not the point here, I think, since when I pop elements of the heap, one by one, I get a proper order that is:

1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 4 3, 10 1

Here is what my code in python looks like: (I am using the heapq library for implementing the priority queue)
To add elements to the heap:

```
[deadline, minutes] = map( int, raw_input().split() )
heapq.heappush( heap, ( deadline, minutes ) )
```

To remove them from the heap:

```
d, m = heapq.heappop( heap )
```

Here is the output I get when I print the heap, followed by popping elements from the heap step by step:

Heap:  [(1, 1), (2, 1), (4, 3), (10, 1), (2, 2)]
Job taken:  1 1
Job taken:  2 1
Job taken:  2 2
Job taken:  4 3
Job taken:  10 1

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was actually looking at the object during debugging the program(rather than printing out them). But when I print out the values, they were all sorted.

Comment: Did you actually solve this on interviewstreet with this approach?  Since they ask for the answer for each prefix of the input (i.e. max overshoot for 1st job, for 1st & 2nd, for first three, etc.), solving each one individually will be at least O(n^2) (and is O(n^2 log n) with a heapq).

I had to do something more sophisticated to share information between these prefixes and got the complexity down to O(n log n)

Comment: @SumuduFernando How did you do it? I've been struggling with it for some time now.

Comment: I doubt I could explain it in the space of a comment; the key idea was that no matter what subset of tasks you're doing, optimally you'll do the ones with closer deadlines first (try to prove that first).  Then to extend the solution for the first k tasks to include task (k+1), I need some way to track information about the ones that are more urgent than task (k+1).  I used something similar to a binary index tree to efficiently store this info (I can't find any references for the version I learned) for this.  Clear as mud?

Comment: @SumuduFernando Thanks for the hint! Yes, I had already proven why the earliest deadline first is optimal. I was stuck on trying to extend it for the next incoming task. I'll try to work out how to use binary index trees for this.